# Правильно ли происходит обновление поля?

Tags: php, mysql

При заходе на страницу срабатывает следующий код

```
$post = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM app WHERE id = ? AND url = ?');
$post->execute(array($id,$url));
$game = $post->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY);
$views = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE app SET views=views+1 WHERE id = ?');
$views->execute(array($id));
```

1. Если одновременно зайдет несколько пользователей на страницу, правильным ли будет подсчет поля `views`? То есть открыли 10 человек страницу одновременно. Тогда поле `views` обновится 10 раз в порядке очереди?
2. На счет первого запроса. Если я установлю индекс на поле `url`, выборка будет осуществляться быстрее?

Comment: 1. Да, 2. Да :D

Comment: 1. Да, корректно. 2. А по одному id у вас много записей ? если да - то нужен составной индекс `id, url`. Два индекса одновременно mysql использовать не умеет, будет выбран только один. поэтому есть смысл в этот один индекс и включить оба поля

Comment: @Mike ~500, выборку по `url` сделал для гарантий, вдруг какой-то не тот `id` выберет

Comment: @emtecif Т.е. id боле менее уникальный. тогда не надо индекс на url, только добавление записей замедлит, а использоваться для поиска по факту не будет

Comment: @Mike как понять более менее уникальный?) id ведь в любом случае уникальный, 1,2,3 и т.д, он ведь не будет повторятся.

Comment: @emtecif Ну вы структуру таблиц не привели. Я исходил из предположения (видя ваш запрос), что id был назначен в какой то другой таблице, а в этой несколько записей с одним id. поэтому и "более менее" :)

Answer (score 1):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

1. Да, корректно.
2. А по одному `id` у вас много записей ? Если да - то нужен составной индекс `id`, `url`. Два индекса одновременно mysql использовать не умеет, будет выбран только один. Поэтому есть смысл в этот один индекс и включить оба поля.